# Global Payment method showing Blank Screen after successful Transaction

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, global

I am using Global Payment method in one of my website and since 2 months I am not getting any proper solution to resolve blank screen after successful payment transaction. Please provide me solution ASAP those who anyone knows about it.

Thanks,

Comment: I assume by blank screen you mean a blank white screen. That is what can be called a white screen of death. Usually it is a fatal php error that the error classes cannot catch. You'd need to check the server error logs (not just the magento ones) and update the question wit the error.

Comment: @MarkRees Please find the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/vxmep2 for the server error log

Comment: That seems to be the access log and not the error log and apart from the 400 status on the customer sections I don't see anything.